# SCSS Foundation 5 on Archlinux not compiling

Tags: node.js, sass, zurb-foundation, bower, archlinux

I run Archlinux and installed Foundation 5 using these instructions: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html

After doing:
    `sudo npm install -g bower grunt-cli`

I installed foundation, and started a new project.

However when I try to compile scss by using the command:
    `bundle exec compass watch`

and modifying app.scss I get the error:

```
error /home/pampuchy/myproject/scss/_settings.scss (Line 58: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/functions
```

I have looked around on the net and it seems like bower and nodejs are unable to find where my scss files live.

My config.rb has the line:
    `add_import_path "./bower_components/foundation/scss"`

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

i can answer my own question: using emacs, i had scss-mode turned on. this seems to cause the problem. i removed scss-mode and now everything works.